# Wordpress Dropdown Menus Out On Page Load

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, drop-down-menu, navigation

My site [Campfire Inc](http://mycustomdevelopment.com/campfire/) Is displaying the dropdown navigation on page load. On hover it retracts. I am wondering if this is an issue with the [theme](http://320press.com/wp-foundation/) or with some jquery. How do i fix it if the error is in jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep. In style.css on line 221 add:

```
display:none;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a 404 error (file not found) on a css file:

```
http://mycustomdevelopment.com/campfire/wp-content/themes/campfire/stylesheets/app.css?ver=3.0
```

.flyout elements should have a css property like:

```
display: none
```

that is probably in that file.

Comment: I will look into the missing CSS file! Thank you.